Why is the accuracy of NSolve's solutions for equations with multiple roots lower than the accuracy of the original coefficients?
Try the following code
sol1 = NSolve[N[Expand[(x^3 - Sqrt[2]x - 1)^3], 50] == 0];
sol2 = NSolve[N[(x^3 - Sqrt[2]x - 1)^3, 50] == 0];
{Accuracy[sol1], Accuracy[sol2]}
(* {15.8654, 48.9868} *)

I wonder why the accuracy of sol1 is lower than sol2 and how to get the high-precision roots of the polynomial equation with multiple roots in expanded form.

In the calculation of a polynomial in expanded form you can get a lot of cancellation. To get an accurate result, Increase the precision to e.g. 150

Assuming NSolve does not expand a power, only one actually needs to deal with multiplicity while the other gets it for free.

This Q&A may be closed, but I'm not sure it should be. I wonder how many users have had a course in numerical analysis or even just understand the numerics of solving polynomial equations. One might get a detailed analysis by asking on scicomp.SE.
Two comments form a pretty good answer:

In the calculation of a polynomial in expanded form you can get a lot of cancellation. To get an accurate result, Increase the precision to e.g. 150 –
Daniel Huber Sep 7 at 8:01


Assuming NSolve does not expand a power, only one actually needs to deal with multiplicity while the other gets it for free. –
Daniel Lichtblau Sep 7 at 17:52


Agreed it is a reasonable numerical analysis question.
